# Receiving a file with sockets

Tags: c, sockets

I'd like to receive a file over sockets in my c program, for which I made a function `recvfile_all`. It receives the file in chunks based on the parameter `data`.
`struct filedata` is defined as

```
struct filedata {
    struct stat st;
    char filename[FILENAME_MAX];
};
```

The code for my function is-

```
// Receive a file based on filedata. Return the number of bytes
// left to receive in case of error
size_t recvfile_all(int sock, const struct filedata *data) {
    size_t to_recv = data->st.st_size;     // total data to receive for a file
    size_t recv;                           // length of data to receive once
    char *buffer = malloc(0);              // buffer to hold chunk
    size_t chunk_s = data->st.st_blksize;  // chunk size to receive file in
    size_t supp_to_recv;

    FILE *file = fopen(data->filename, "w");
    if (file == NULL) return to_recv;

    while (to_recv) {
        // receive a chunk if we have more to receive than the size of a
        // single chunk, otherwise receive whatever is left
        recv = to_recv > chunk_s ? chunk_s : to_recv;
        supp_to_recv = recv;
        buffer = realloc(buffer, recv);
        recvall(sock, (char *)buffer, &recv);

        if (recv < supp_to_recv)
            return to_recv - recv;  // return how much is left to receive

        fwrite(buffer, 1, recv, file);  // write what was received to file
        to_recv -= recv;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return to_recv;
}
```

The function `recv_all` is a function that's similar to `send_all` from Beej's Guide to Network Programming. It simply receives a number of bytes from a socket. I've tested it multiple times and it has worked fine, I don't think the error is in this function. It's defined as-

```
int recvall(int s, char *buf, size_t *len) {
    size_t total = 0;         // how many bytes we've recveived
    size_t bytesleft = *len;  // how many we have left to receive
    size_t n;

    while (total < *len) {
        n = recv(s, buf + total, bytesleft, 0);
        if (n == -1 || n == 0) {
            break;
        }
        total += n;
        bytesleft -= n;
    }

    *len = total;  // return number actually sent here

    return n == -1 ? -1 : 0;  // return -1 onm failure, 0 on success
}
```

My function doesn't seem to work. Any ideas why?
Also, the error is definitely not in the code that sends the file, I've already tested that multiple times.

Comment: *How* doesn't it seem to work? What is supposed to happen? What actually happens? When there's an error (in the sender or in the receiver) do you print out what the error is? Have you used a debugger to step through the code? What is actually being sent?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It receives garbage data mixed in with a little bit of what was actually supposed to be received, and there is no error while executing

Comment: Does `recv` ever return `-1` or `0`? Have you tried printing some information about that when it happens? And how do you detect the "garbage" data? What are you actually sending? Is it a *binary* file or a *text* file?

Comment: And what's the business with the `realloc` calls in the loop? Why not have a fixed-size buffer to receive the data? That should simplify a lot of the code in `recvfile_all`. Simpler code means less chances of problems or errors, while also making it easier to debug.

Comment: `recv` does not return `-1` or `0`. I can see that data received is garbage because it's a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the function works fine, I was using a linked list to send the files, and because of a previous mistake, the server receives the header of the files that the client is about to sent in reverse order, rectifying that fixed the problem